# Using Ubuntu Server 18.04 as iSCSI target and Windows 10 nodes

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, pxe, iscsi

I´m starting to look at the possibility in running a iSCSI-target from a Ubuntu Server 18.04 to deploy image file (golden image file) to boot Win10-nodes(diskless) in a network.

I have a running setup with Ubuntu Server supplying via PXE, TFTP and a DHCP-server the needed image file to boot Linux nodes in the same network. That setup works as expected as its setup was fairly straight forward. 
However some users in the network request Win10 (or some other Windows-version) as their preferred OS and I must therefore commit to the challenge and support them as well.
I have read various guides telling how to setup Ubuntu Server as iSCSI-target (e.g. https://kifarunix.com/how-to-install-and-configure-iscsi-storage-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

A search doesn´t find any compelling answers, it seems that most answers rely on the fact that the server supplying/holding image-files is a Windows Server. Surely this must not be the single solution?

Anyone tried to boot Win10 images from a Ubuntu Server via iSCSI (and PXE)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a different solution, which doesn´t require me to run Windows Server nor an additional network setup holding a  iSCSI-target/initiator.
I realized that I can simply run a virtual machine from the ubuntu-client with the requested software and applications needed. In addition letting the virtual machine be on the same network, via the bridged network alternative the virtual machine can be accessible by any other computer in the network.

This might help someone else whom shares the same issue.